# Erro de inserção de parâmetros no Banco de dados (com arquivos que possuem o mesmo codigo)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Olá para aqueles que estao lendo a pergunta gostaria de auxilio com um problema de insert que estou enfretando com um programa de cadastro que encontrei na internet
e ao fazer a primeira versao ela não apresentou nenhum tipo de erro , porém ao copiar este mesmo codigo e apenas mudar nomes de inputs e adicionar algumas  variaveis para que fossem compativeis com o novo banco que estava usando presenciei a mensagem que coloquei caso ocorre-se um erro de inserção "O usuario não pode ser adicionado ao banco de dados" e busquei encontrar o erro mas os codigos são praticamente os mesmos porem com nomes de variaveis diferentes e campos adicionais
e não tive sucesso em encontrar o erro e gostaria de um ponto de vista diferente para indentificar o erro e se possivel deixem marcado a linha

para aqueles que desejam saber de onde tirei o codigo eis o link do video com o codigo original
desde já agradeço :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgSysHTsb6A&t=479s

codigo form.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo bem.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fazendo a insercao dos parametros no formulario form.php
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

insercao no banco do form.php sem erros
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

resultado da insercao dos parametros no banco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formulario que esta com o erro

codigo form2.php (formulario com o erro)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo bem2.php (apos a insercao do form2 a pagina seria redirecionada para o bem2.php)

codigo bem.php junto do erro que ocorreu apos a insercao no form2.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

banco form1 banco: account tabela: user

1   idPrimária  int(11)     AUTO_INCREMENT

2   username    varchar(100)
3   email   varchar(100)
    4   password    varchar(100)
    5   avatar  varchar(100)

banco form2 banco:  area  tabela: teste

1      idpacientePrimária  int(100)    AUTO_INCREMENT
    2   nome    varchar(100)
    3   email   varchar(100)
    4   senha   int(100)
    5   cpf varchar(100)
    6   endereco    varchar(100)
    7   avatar  varchar(100)

Comment: Arthur, boa noite, quando for nos mostrar trechos de código por gentileza ao invés de prints copie e cole o código aqui porque facilita a visualização!

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, boa noite, repare que no seu código você está criptografando com `MD5` a sua senha, no entanto no seu banco, a coluna 'senha' é `int`, caso essa criptografia possua letras ele jamais irá salvar, acredito que por isso no seu exemplo funcional o campo password era do tipo `varchar`.